# changing the action to an ajax loaded form using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form i'm loading in via ajax. The form loads fine. What i'm trying to do is append a string to the forms action but i'm not having any luck. It doesn't seem to change the action value. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```
$('#editForm').load(itemDetails[20]+'?A=Edit',function(){

    var wAction = $('#webAppForm').attr('action')+'&amp;PageID=/thank-you-renewal';
    $('#wAction').attr('action',wAction);   

    console.log(wAction);
    return false;
});

console.log returns the original action.
```

Comment: `'#wAction'` is unlikely to be the selector you want.

Comment: Yes #webAppForm != #wAction

Comment: Judging by this code it seems you have 2 forms. One with id 'webAppForm' and another with id 'wAction'. Please confirm.

Comment: DOH!!!!! Such a dope.... thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this

```
var wAction = $('#webAppForm');
wAction.attr('action', wAction.attr('action') + '?PageID=thank-you-renewal');

console.log($('#webAppForm').attr('action')); // someAction?PageID=thank-you-renewal
```